# How can I access firestore data before authenticating phone number?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my flutter app I want to create a phone authentication for sign up, with one condition that only those phone numbers, which are already been stored in firestore database can sign up.. ..... How can I access firestore data before signing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a blocking function for `beforeCreate` event and check that a user's [phoneNumber](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.userrecord.md#userrecordphonenumber) is in a list of allowed numbers. If not throw an error.

> Triggers before a new user is saved to the Firebase Authentication database, and before a token is returned to your client app.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.beforeCreate = functions.auth.user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {
  // TODO check user.phoneNumber againts allowed ones
});
```

See [Extend Firebase Authentication with blocking Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule set for firebase access on the firebase application console.

This is a good place to look:

[Firestore Security Rules Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)